# How to manually execute SQL query in CakePHP without a model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm writing a quick throwaway method to import users from an old table to my new cake app. I've imported the old users table (old_users) into my cake app db. Basically I need to just do a select all form the old_users table, then loop through them and add them to the new users table using somehting like $newuser->create('old_username', 'old_password');

However, I didnt want to create a model etc for the temp table as this import will only be run once. So my question is - how can I do a basic select to get all the users from this table from a cake method within the users controller. I was thinking somehting like this:

```
public function admin_importOldUsers() {
        $db = $this->getDataSource();
        $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM old_users');
    }
```

But it failswith the error:

> Call to undefined method UsersController::getDataSource()

I cant find much in the docs on how to query another db table (without a model) from within a controller....

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To manually run a standard SQL query in CakePHP without a model, you can use the `query` method on any model that is available to the controller (it doesn't matter which model you use):

```
class MyController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $result = $this->AnyModel->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
    }
}
```

[CakePHP 1.3 - Models](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#query)

Comment: But what If I want to use `JOIN` in query? I want to call multiple models

Comment: @Kunok This method just allows you to write a raw SQL query - you can put a join in if you like, it doesn't matter. If you want to use the actual ORM models in your Cake app then you don't want to use this method. Read the documentation about the Cake query builder, and how to join associated data.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation about that part is incorrect.
Find the name of the connection in your *database.php* file and use the following code (mine is *default*):

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource("default"); // name of your database connection
$places_of_interest = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM places_of_interest");
```

Comment: thanks, is working! all other examples say to use `query` that not works! [ex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18168185/287948)

Comment: Nice solution! I can only add, that also it's possible not to "hardcode" connection name, but write `$this->useDbConfig`. In my case it was: `$datasourceName = $this->Chunk_section->useDbConfig; $db= &ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasourceName);`, where `Chunk_section` - any model name. It can be useful, if there is different connection in localhost and prod. server.

Comment: Not worked for me, getting error `Fatal error: Class 'ConnectionManager' not found`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once for a database conversion script for a non-Cake DB to a Cake one. Here are some bits from that script (based on CakePHP 1.3, might be slightly different if you use 2.x).

```
// Require the config/database.php file for DB connection
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php');
$DB = new DATABASE_CONFIG();

// Setup the connection
if($DB->default['driver'] === 'mysqli') {
    // Connect using MySQLi
    print "Connecting to database: ";
    $dbc = new mysqli($DB->default['host'], $DB->default['login'], $DB->default['password'], $DB->default['database']);

    // Make sure we use UTF8 encoding
    if($DB->default['encoding'] == "UTF8") {
        $dbc->set_charset($DB->default['encoding']);
    }

    // At this point you can just run raw queries like:
    $dbc->query("INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Management'), (2, 'Operations')");

    // Close the database connection
    $dbc->close();
} else {
    die("Please use mysqli");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so is that outside of cake? Thing is I need to really do it within a controller as I need to be able to create the users for Auth and ACL purposes, along with hashing the password.

Answer (score 0):

Have no chance to try it right now but below code should work.

```
class NoModelsController extends AppController{
    var $name="NoModels";
    var $uses = null;  

    public function admin_importOldUsers() {
        $results = $this->Model->query('SELECT * FROM old_users');
        pr($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as that controller doesnt have a model I get this:

Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is:

$model = $this->loadModel('Your Model name')->query("SELECT * FROM  Table name")